# RTC client: get current work item?

Tags: rational-team-concert

I'm looking for a way to extend the RTC client to get the current work item programmatically, or even better add a listener that notifies me whenever the current work item is changed.

I don't know where to start. Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

One can use the following code to get the `IWorkItemActivationManager`:

```
IWorkItemActivationManager manager = ClientModel.getWorkItemActivationManager();
```

Wie this manager, it is possible to use the method `getActiveWorkItem` to get a `IWorkItemHandle`:

```
IWorkItemHandle handle = manager.getActiveWorkItem();
```

Then the following code can be used to get the `IWorkItem`:

```
IAuditableClient auditableClient= (IAuditableClient) Controller.getInstance().getTeamRepository().getClientLibrary(IAuditableClient.class);
IWorkItem item = auditableClient.resolveAuditable(handle, com.ibm.team.workitem.common.model.IWorkItem.FULL_PROFILE, null);
```

The `ClientModel` is in the following package: `com.ibm.team.workitem.rcp.core`

Answer (score 1):

One way I usually explore is the OSLC API through REST call.
With a Chrome and its "Developer Tool" activated, I click on the web client and look at the request done.
That gives an indication of the kind of service involved.

Then you can look at "[How to consume the Rational Team Concert change management services](https://jazz.net/library/article/352)", which illustrates how those services are structured.

Combine it with "[Extending Rational Team Concert 3.x](https://jazz.net/library/article/784/)" and you can start from there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The problem is, I do not think that there is any communication with the server involved. I thin the current work item is only set in the IDE.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException true, yet a bridge like ClearCase is able to track that state in order to define its own current activity: https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/3.0?p=news&pp=true#cc-bridge

Comment: Thanks for all the hints. I finally found a method to get it using plain Java API. I added an answer to this question.